# Do websockets share data with multiple instances with google app engine flexible environment?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, websocket, socket.io

I'm using nodejs and socket.io with socket.io-redis to share it's state with multiple nodejs instances.(cluster, multiple ec2 instances...)

I heard app engine flexible environment supports websocket. Dose it mean that I don't need to use redis adaptor in app engine? or I still need to use adaptor to share websockets in multiple instances?

I read documents but I can't understand exactly benefit of app engine with websocket.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I*m kinda in the same boat